# MFTBOX.exe auto start during screen shot; how to stop

Tags: screenshot, autostart

This tool pops up when ever I am taking a screen shot.
The exe is location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Canon\MF Toolbox Ver4.9\MFTBOX.exe
```

Not sure what it does and why it keeps showing up.
Is there a way to actually stop it from showing up apart from uninstalling it?

Comment: This is when you take a screenshot using Shirt-PrtScr?  Does Alt-PrtScr also trigger it?  Have you looked in the Cannon MF Toolbox's setting for a way to disable that "feature"?

Comment: Alt-PrtScr does trigger it. Not sure what the Shirt-PrtScr is. Canon MF Toolbox does not seem like having an option to disable auto start.

Comment: Sorry "Shift" PrtScr.  Perhaps, how about you tell us how you are triggering it/taking a screenshot? :)

Comment: I usually do, Alt-PrtScr and then mspaint (Using Windows + R). Strangely it happens for the first time I am taking screenshot after a system start. Once I close the popup it does not appear again.